# Using .animate with :lt() Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate

I have the following working code which is executed onclick:

```
  $waste.append($stock
    .children('.container:lt(3)')
    .css( 'left', function(i) {return ['0rem', '2rem', '4rem'][i];})
  );
```

It shows 3 div's positioned 0, 2 and 4 rem from a left div border. This all shows up correct.

BUT....I don't want these 3 DIVs just to appear on their given location, I want to move them to that location. How to do this? I've tried things like:

```
  $waste.append($stock
    .children('.container:lt(3)')
    .animate( left: function(i) {return ['0rem', '2rem', '4rem'][i];}, 200)
  );
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Anyone has an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Add transition in css:

```
.container {
    transition: left .5s ease;
}
```